# python: creating a list inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I just started using python and I'm trying to create a program that will read a file that looks like this:

```
AAA x 111
AAB x 111
AAA x 112
AAC x 123
...
```

the file is 50 lines long and I'm trying to make the letters into keys in a dictionary and the numbers lists that correspond with the keys.

I want the output to look like this:

```
{AAA: ['111', '112'], AAB: ['111'], AAC: [123], ...}
```

This is what I've tried

```
file = open("filename.txt", "r") 
readline = file.readline().rstrip()
while readline!= "":
    list = []
    list = readline.split(" ")
    j = list.index("x")
    k = list[0:j]
    v = list[j + 1:]
    d = {}
    if k not in d == False:
        d[k] = []
    d[k].append(v)
    readline = file.readline().rstrip()
```

I keep getting syntax errors on my if statement and I can't figure out what I've done wrong.

Comment: You could consolidate `list = []` and `list = readline.split(" ")` into just `list = readline.split(" ")`- by redefining `list`, you're making the previous definition disappear. Also, `str.split` returns a list.

Comment: Also, try to stay away from using `list` as a variable name - `list` is a [builtin](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

Comment: @kuyan - I think your second example is supposed to be `list = readline.split()`?

Comment: @Aesthete: You're right, I wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing colons at the ends, also you could write this like:

```
if k not in d:
    d[k] = [v]
else:
    d[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need colons at the ends of your if statements; this version should work:

```
   if k in d == False:
      d[k] = []
      d[k].append(v)
   else:
      d[k].append(v)
```

Comment: This is bad in a few ways. Firstly, ``if k not in d:`` would read better, you repeat `d[k].append(v)` instead of moving it outside the `if`, and you introduce a race condition into your code by not `try`ing then catching the exception, but rather by checking beforehand. It's not likely to be a problem, but it's still a bad idea.

Comment: I followed your comments and cleaned up the code slightly. Now when the program executes I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 2):

Makes your life a little easier with `defaultdict`

```
>>> out = defaultdict(list)
>>> with open('test.txt') as f:
      for line in f.readlines():
        x = line.split()
        out[x[0]].append(int(x[2]))
```

It's also good practice to use the `with` statement to open files, when possible. Your original example had two entries as `str`, and one as `int`, I have just converted all to `int` here.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)!  Aside from your missing colon, as mentioned by others, you could replace the whole `if` with this:

```
from collections import defaultdict # placed with your other imports, probably
....
d = defaultdict(lambda:[])
d[k].append(v)
```

Comment: The argument to the `defaultdict` constructor must be callable.

Comment: I tried replacing the if statement with the defaultdict but I get a TypeError: first argument must be callable

Comment: Sorry!  My fault for not testing.  Now using a `lambda` to make a constructor that returns the empty list.  Aesthete's solution with the `list` constructor is probably better, but I'll leave it like this as another solution.